# How to fix "Syntax error in module lambda_function"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm trying to run a lambda function to stop EC2 instances. But instead I'm having errors.

tried to add return{print 'stopped your instances: ' + str(instances)} and other stuff. But it doesn't work.

Appreciate your help in pointing out the problem. Thank you

```
import boto3

# Region your instances are in, e.g. 'us-east-1'
region = 'ap-southeast-1'

# Instances ID: ex. ['X-XXXXXXXX', 'X-XXXXXXXX']
instances = 'i-02dc8a50ad60d1ab0'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'stopped your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

Upon save and running test, it should run successfully and terminate my EC2 instance

Comment: "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 12)",

Comment: line12:     print 'stopped your instances: ' + str(instances)

Comment: Is it running python2 or python3? You should use print like a function and it will work for both. e.g. `print( 'stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because your are running on python3 and `print` is no longer a keyword. It's a function. You have to call it.

e.g.

```
print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

If you use it like this it will work on both versions of python.